# Retrieve code changes after rejected git push

Tags: git, github, gitlab

This is what happened:

1. I started to implement a new feature in a protected branch from push (I forgot to check the branch)
2. Once I was ready to push, I executed: `git add` + `git commit -m "my message"` and `git push`
3. The changes were rejected because I was in a protected branch

But after that, my local git showed the changes as commited/pushed and when I execute `git status`, this is what I have:

```
On branch staging
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is it possible to "undo" the procedure and move my code changes to a new branch, which will be merged to a protected branch via pull request later on?

Comment: What do you mean by "showed as committed/pushed"? Git locally still considers your working folder clean, because you successfully made a commit, locally. If you couldn't push to the server, the remote tracking branch should still be behind though. Does git also state that you're ahead of the remote?

Comment: To move your commits to a new branch, simply create a new branch, then reset the local protected branch back to where the remote says it is. Then you can push your new branch and issue a pull request to the protected branch from it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, git says that I am ahead of remote

Comment: Thank you @LasseV.Karlsen, it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

To move your commits to a new branch, you can do the following:

1. Make sure you do not have any uncommitted changes before doing this, one of the steps below will do a hard reset, which will wipe out such changes

   **If in doubt, make a backup of your entire working folder, with the .git repository inside, to make sure you don't mess anything up**
2. Make sure you have the feature branch that is protected checked out locally, at your latest commit, the one you didn't manage to push
3. Create a new branch:

   ```
   git branch new-feature-branch
   ```

   *(note, this does not check out the new branch, so you're still on the previous feature branch, the one that is protected)*
4. Reset the feature branch back to where the remote says it is

   assuming your remote is origin:

   ```
   git reset --hard origin/feature-branch-name
   ```
5. Check out and push your new branch

   ```
   git checkout new-feature-branch
   git push --set-upstream origin new-feature-branch
   ```
6. Go through the pull request process in gitlab or github